# Reference to MediaRecorder object is undefined in function, despite being initialized in previously called function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, web-mediarecorder

I'm developing a React application to record both audio and video from the user and then fetch it to a backend.

In the `MediaRecorderComponent` below, the function `initializeDevice` asks the user to allow audio or video recording (it's called from clicking a button since our users need our application UI to be as clear and explicit as possible) and, if granted, initializes the `mediaRecorder` variable to a new `MediaRecorder` object, receiving as argument the response from the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` promise.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { RecordAudioButton } from '../Components';

type Props = {
    mediaConstraints: MediaStreamConstraints;
};

function MediaRecorderComponent({ mediaConstraints }: Props) {
    const [permissionGranted, setPermissionGranted] = useState(false);
    const [stream, setStream] = useState<null | MediaStream>(null);
    const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);

    let mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder;

    const initializeDevice = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
                mediaConstraints
            );
            setStream(response);
            setPermissionGranted(true);
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(response);
        } catch (err) {
            setPermissionGranted(false);
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    const handleRecording = () => {
        if (isRecording) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            setIsRecording(false);
        }

        mediaRecorder.start();
        setIsRecording(true);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {permissionGranted ? (
                <RecordAudioButton
                    isRecording={isRecording}
                    onClick={handleRecording}
                />
            ) : (
                <>
                    <p>
                        CLIENT INSTRUCTIONS
                    </p>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => initializeDevice()}
                    >
                        Let's start!
                    </button>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Later on, the `handleRecording` is passed as a prop to another component, which calls it when its `div` is clicked on:

```js
function RecordAudioButton({ isRecording, onClick }: Props) {
    return (
        <div
            className="bg-error text-base-100 rounded-full p-5 shadow-lg"
            onClick={() => onClick()}
        >
        ///... and so on
```

However, when the button is clicked I receive a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start')` triggered when the `handleRecording` function calls `mediaRecorder.start()`, and the `mediaRecorder` variable appears as `undefined`, even although it was initialized when the user granted permission in the `initializeDevice` function.

Why would the reference be uninitialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ref to store your value:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
    ...
    const mediaRecorder = useRef(null);

    const initializeDevice = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
                mediaConstraints
            );
            setStream(response);
            setPermissionGranted(true);
            mediaRecorder.current = new MediaRecorder(response);
        } catch (err) {
            setPermissionGranted(false);
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    const handleRecording = () => {
        if (isRecording) {
            mediaRecorder.current.stop();
            setIsRecording(false);
        }

        mediaRecorder.current.start();
        setIsRecording(true);
    };
    ...
```

Changing the values in your ref will not cause a rerender and will persist the value even when a render occurs provided that the component is not unmounted.

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.